# How long does it take for beer to become untasty?

Tags: taste, drinking

I cannot drink beer fast. So when I opened a bottle or can or poured my beer into a glass, it starts to became warm and untasty with time. When I am out, or in a bar, I cannot really keep it cold.

At room temperature, how long can I drink my beer before it starts to get warmer and the taste begins to change when it comes directly from fridge or a cooler?

Comment: Depends on how cold it was to begin with.

Comment: Oppssss. Question edited to add that derail.

Comment: Sounds like a physics question to me. There are a lot of variables including starting volume, how fast you drink, atmospheric pressure, shape and type of container, [whether the beer is stirred](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/cooling-a-cup-of-coffee-with-help-of-a-spoon), etc. and so on.  For me, I can keep drinking the same beer for as long as the poker game lasts. ;-)

Comment: Agreed that this is a bad question.  There are huge numbers of variables and one missing one is what kind of beer it is.  Some beers are better to drink warm and especially if you go with some specialty beers, some may not be carbonated to begin with (and therefore don't go flat).  This can't be answered other than "it depends."